# Shared element activity transition between fragments in separate activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

Shared element transitions are with us for a considerable time now and still there are some things that are not (at least explicitly) said.

My problem is following:
I have two activities, lets call them FirstActivity and SecondActivity. Both of them have their fragments, FirstFragment is settled in FirstActivity and SecondFragment is in SecondActivity.

Element that I want animated is in FirstFragment. His transition destination is in SecondFragment.

Research has gotten me to a (I hope wrong) conclusion that what I want to achieve is not possible.

My question for you guys is: is there a possibility to make this work or should I move my logic from SecondFragment to SecondActivity and ditch the fragment?

Comment: Just to note to future animation explorers, solution was not found. Best thing I could do (and did) was to move my logic to activity and ditched the fragment. If you absolutely, positively need a fragment, good luck and please share your success story with all of us.